# Pandas runs out of memory on reading reasonably small CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-requests

Im trying to read a small `csv` file, but I keep running out of memory after waiting 3 to 4 minutes.

I've tried googling, and most problems people had, were with files of 8 gb and more.
This one is `45mb`, has roughly `160k rows` and `64 columns`, so my guess is that something else is going wrong.

I've tried different settings in the `pd.read_csv()` function:
`sep=','`
`quotechar='"'`
`low_memory=False`

Did not work, heres the code which did **not work** (tried with StringIO as well):

**Code 1**

```
pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Erfan Nariman\Desktop\ongevallen.txt', 
            sep=',',
            quotechar='"',
            encoding='latin1')
```

**Code 2**

```
rawdata = open(r'C:\Users\Erfan Nariman\Desktop\ongevallen.txt', 'r', )
rawtext = rawdata.read()

pd.read_csv(StringIO(rawtext), 
            sep=',',
            quotechar='"',
            encoding='latin1')
```

So the following **worked**:
Uploaded the file to dropbox and read the text with `requests`

```
def read_ongevallen():

    url = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1i7nne11tc1ki4d/ongevallen.txt?dl=0'

    rawdata = requests.get(url).text

    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(rawdata), 
                sep=',',
                quotechar='"',
                encoding='latin1',
                low_memory=False)

    return df
```

Kind of clueless why the most convenient methods are not working and the latter does?

[Link to file for testing](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1i7nne11tc1ki4d/ongevallen.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Might not be Python/Pandas that's using all the ram then but the OS opening the file. Run top and then run the script and see which process is doing the eating?

Comment: could you just try `pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Erfan Nariman\Desktop\ongevallen.txt')` with `%timeit` and let me know how much time its taking?

Comment: The last snippet worked on my machine **even after reading from disk and not from dropbox**.

Comment: This is actually weird. After @Neil suggestion, I re-opened my `Jupyter Notebook` and `Chrome`, ran the same exact code, and now it works.

It must have been something to do with `Chrome` using too much memory, although I had maybe 10 tabs open.

Thanks everyone for the answers.

Comment: @PuneetSinha this is the `%timeit` output:  
`1.42 s ± 33.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`